# jquery onclick event for <a> and <span> tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have following menu items:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li><a><span></span>Category1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a><span></span>Categor2y</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to capture `<a>` and `<span>` for different onclick events. I tried it like this:

```
 $(".nav li > a").click(function(){
        //something
 });

$(".nav li > a > span").click(function(){
        //something
    });
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure its possible like this? If used clicked `<span>` relatively he click `<a>` .

Comment: try event.stopPropagation in span on click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the bubbling up of click event from the `span` to the anchor element

```
$(".nav li > a").click(function () {
    //something
});

$(".nav li > a > span").click(function (e) {
    //you need to prevent the bubbling up of the event here
    e.stopPropagation();
    //something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

give it in document.ready. It should work

```
$(document.).ready(function()
{$(".nav li > a").click(function(){
    //something
 });

$(".nav li > a > span").click(function(){
    //something
});});
```

Comment: I tried this already, but it didn't work. The proposal from Arun P Johny works. Nevertheless thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to differentiate the target and handle it accordingly

```
$(document.).ready(function()
{$(".nav li > a").click(function(evt){

if(evt.target.tagName == "SPAN")
{
////
}

else
{
///
}

 });
```

});